# MySQL Error "right syntax to use near '/*100,3), '%') AS `Percentage` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, navicat

I got this weird error after trying to execute a query on a large table:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '/*100,3),
>   '%') AS `Percentage` FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE
>   QUERY_ID=' at line 1

What does it mean?

EDIT == this is the query

```
update cities w, states s set w.region_id = s.id 
where s.code = w.region and w.country_id = s.country_id
```

The cities table has around 3 million entries and the states table around 6000

Just for the record I executed this query using a mysql client Navicat.

Comment: Its an update query involving two tables - it works fine on a smaller table.

Comment: Can you post the code for your SQL query?  It sounds like you have a syntax error in your SQL statement.

Comment: I know this item is old, but I wanted to add a note here in case someone else encounters this error as I did this morning while performing a left join against two large tables. Navicat appears to no longer be working, but it is in fact still processing the query. If you just wait it out, it will complete, or at least throw a helpful error. The error listed above only happens when you terminate the query early.

Answer (score 2):

SQL supports C-style comments:

```
/* ... */
```

so it looks like `/*100,3` is being interpreted as the beginning of a comment and that comment is wrecking the syntax of the rest of the SQL.

Comment: @Ali: Have you enabled [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/profiling-table.html)? Is your surrounding environment trying to access profiling information?

Comment: ummm I'm not sure about that - how do I check and why exactly shoudl I enable it?

Comment: @Ali: Look for "profiling" in `show variables;`. Also try running your  SQL from the `mysql` shell. You also might want to include details of how you're accessing MySQL in your question (i.e. what language, ORM, library, ...).

Comment: I'm using Navicat MySQL client here...would that have any bearing on the whole issue?

Comment: @Ali: That might be involved. Sorry but I don't know anything about Navicat. You should add that information to your question, I added the tag for you.